# Who was the Old Red Cracker?

Tags: history

I have heard countless stories on the Old Red Cracker, also known as +ORC, being the founding father of reverse engineering tutorials.

I also read somewhere that he left some riddles to find his "secret page" and he disappeared into thin air.

Did anyone *really* solve these riddles? Is the identity, or some of the background, of that person known?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a person, a persona, or Internet culture, but not about reverse engineering.

Comment: @Gilles: Do you have any idea where this sort of question would be on-topic, then?

Comment: @JasonGeffner Try not to *create* too many tags for the purpose of tagging *one question* correctly. If a new tag is absolutely needed, then create just the *one* most relevant tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the riddle was solved. See http://www.home.aone.net.au/~byzantium/found/found4.html

As for +ORC himself, there's some more info at http://www.woodmann.com/crackz/Orc.htm

The last time I spoke with Fravia+ about +ORC, Fravia+ said that +ORC became obsessed with the pyramids in Egypt and went there to study them. He contracted some kind of illness while there and died rather suddenly. If I remember correctly, Fravia+ learned of +ORC's death through +ORC's son.

Comment: Strange, both Fravia+ and +ORC died "suddenly". I smell a conspiracy! In any case, CrackZ and Basilisk both give some suggestions. But it seems that no one will ever know for sure. Certainly not if +ORC is dead now. Him having a son (which is old enough to contact Fravia+, I guess) means that he's probably older than suggseted in CrackZ's page.

Comment: No offence, but I think what you say is just a tale...